# Long string date to short date R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a df with dates formatted in the following way.

```
Date                     Year
<chr>                    <dbl>
Sunday, Jul 27           2008
Tuesday, Jul 29          2008
Wednesday, July 31 (1)   2008
Wednesday, July 31 (2)   2008
```

Is there a simple way to achieve the following format of columns and values? I'd also like to remove the (1) and (2) notations on the two July 31 dates.

```
Date         Year    Month    Day    Day_of_Week
2008-07-27   2008    07       27     Sunday
```

Comment: If you are going to do a lot of date manipulation I would look at the lubridate package which has a lot of flexibility.

Comment: You should post the dput() version of structures like that (it's probably a tibble and somewhat difficult to re-create accurately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dat = data_frame(date = c('Sunday, Jul 27','Tuesday, Jul 29', 'Wednesday, July 
31 (1)','Wednesday, July 31 (2)'), year=rep(2008,4))  

dat %>% 
    mutate(date = gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(date)),
           date = parse_date_time(date,'A, b! d ')) -> dat1
           year(dat1$date)  <-  dat1$year

# A tibble: 4 × 2
        date  year
      <dttm> <dbl>
1 2008-07-27  2008
2 2008-07-29  2008
3 2008-07-31  2008
4 2008-07-31  2008
```

Comment: Please reduce your `library` load to only those packages actually needed; `tidyverse` is a convenience super-package to bring in many many other packages that aren't required here. In this case, I think it would be `dplyr` (and `lubridate`).

Comment: Interesting that you chose to `gsub`-out the annotations from his question. I hadn't thought to do that, good job keeping the question completely/perfectly reproducible.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using just the pertinent packages since tidyverse has eclipsed my usage of any of the individual packages, thanks.

Comment: I've seen a lot of that. That comment goes along with indentation and variable-naming as a "personal preferences" thing, but it also goes along with the SO theme of "minimal/verifiable example". \*shrug\*

Comment: This solution worked very well for me. Appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 4):

With base R, you can do:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Date = c("Sunday, Jul 27" ,"Tuesday, Jul 29", "Wednesday, July 31", "Wednesday, July 31"),
  Year = rep(2008, 4),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


dts <- as.POSIXlt(paste(dat$Year, dat$Date), format = "%Y %A, %B %d")
```

`POSIXlt` provides a list-based reference for the date/time. To see them, try `unclass(dts[1])`.

From here it can be rather academic:

```
dat$Month = 1 + dts$mon # months are 0-based in POSIXlt
dat$Day = dts$mday
dat$Day_of_Week = weekdays(dts)
dat
#                 Date Year Month Day Day_of_Week
# 1     Sunday, Jul 27 2008     7  27      Sunday
# 2    Tuesday, Jul 29 2008     7  29     Tuesday
# 3 Wednesday, July 31 2008     7  31    Thursday
# 4 Wednesday, July 31 2008     7  31    Thursday
```

Comment: I ended up combining your code for the simple month, day, day of week calculations with the lubridate solution above. Thanks for the assistance!